# What is IntegerType?

Tags: go

I saw golang core and found this:

```
func make(t Type, size ...IntegerType) Type
```

What mean IntegerType and Type? It can be C+?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function declaration is from the `builtin` package, [`builtin.make()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make)

```
func make(t Type, size ...IntegerType) Type
```

That `IntegerType` links to: [`builtin.IntegerType`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#IntegerType):

> IntegerType is here for the purposes of documentation only. It is a stand-in for any integer type: int, uint, int8 etc.

So it serves a *documentation purpose*. Since there is no generics in Go, each type that is used in a declaration must be a "real" type (not a type parameter). But most builtin functions are *special*, they allow values of multiple types (or even type "names") to be passed.

To express / document this, the `builtin` package uses the `IntegerType` as a "pseudo" type, a collective type for any integer type.

Similarly, `Type` links to [`builtin.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#Type):

> Type is here for the purposes of documentation only. It is a stand-in for any Go type, but represents the same type for any given function invocation.

This is also for *documentation purposes*. It is also a "pseudo" type that may substitute any types, but Go doesn't support generics to express this using a valid syntax.

Answer (score 5):

**Integer Type :**

> IntegerType is here for the purposes of documentation only. It is a
>   stand-in for any integer type: int, uint, int8 etc.

Ex : `type IntegerType int`

**Type :**

> Type is here for the purposes of documentation only. It is a stand-in
>   for any Go type, but represents the same type for any given function
>   invocation.

Ex: `type Type int`

According to go [document](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#IntegerType)